# Redux and immutables

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am trying to add immutable in the reducer function. However I receive error as `Uncaught TypeError: currentState.merge is not a function` when the data from firebase hits.

Reducer code is as below (commented code is without immutable)

```
import C from '../../constants';
import initialState from '../initialState';
import {Map, List, fromJS} from 'immutable';

const membersInitialState = fromJS(initialState.members);

export default (currentState = membersInitialState, action) => {
  let newstate;
  switch (action.type) {
    case C.RECEIVE_MEMBER_DATA:
    /*return Object.assign({}, currentState, {
      hasReceivedData: true,
      data: action.data
    });*/
    return currentState.merge({
      hasReceivedData: true,
      data: action.data
    });
    //default: return currentState || initialState.members;
  }
  return currentState;
}
```

rootReducer as below

```
import membersReducer from './members';

function rootReducer (state, action){
    return {
        members: membersReducer(state.members, action)
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

[image: debugger screen]

Comment: So what's inside of `currentState`?

Comment: @zerkms just initialState contents

Comment: Is it what you think or what actually there is? I believe it's the former since JS does not agree with you (since it's not obvious why it should be there as soon as you pass a value explicitly)

Comment: updated with a screenshot. this is what i could see..

Comment: It's not what you see: initial state would be there if only the `arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined`. Just check your screenshot once again. So the `currentState` variable holds a JS object (not immutablejs object) which you passed explicitly.

Comment: yes, i understand that.. my doubt is why is the initalstate still in the argument list at index 0.

Comment: Because you have passed it explicitly `membersReducer(state.members, action)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104127/discussion-between-anoop-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was because of `store` creation without using immutable object.

```
export default createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, fromJS(initialState));
```

After updating as above, it is working now.